# pyinstaller still opening console despite using recommended methods to stop this

Tags: python, tkinter, exe, pyinstaller

I have programmed a python script using tkinter and want to turn it into an exe file. I have tried running it as a .pyw file and it only runs the GUI window without the command line which is what I want. However, when using Pyinstaller to convert my script to a .exe file it opens and runs fine but the command line always opens as well. This has happened when converting both .py and .pyw files and it also occurs when I specify in the command prompt --windowed or --noconsole. I have even tried to edit the spec file of my .exe to see if the console is set to true but I find in the code "console=False". I cannot find any other fixes on previous questions or on the pyinstaller issus page and so I have had to ask myself.

This is the spec file

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['D:\\zebsu\\Documents\\simple_calculator_3.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\zebsu'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='simple_calculator_3',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=False )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               name='simple_calculator_3')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly new to Pyinstaller myself but the following command has worked for me:
`pyinstaller -w YourPythonFile.py`.
Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I have just now tried this in response to your advice and it still creates a .exe file that opens up the GUI and a command line when it is excecuted. I have also checked this new file's spec file and it again has console = False despite the console appearing.